# Errors when implementing Simple Image Gallery in Joomla

Tags: image, joomla, gallery

I am working on a website (localHost at this point) using Joomla (2.5) and the Simple Image Gallery extension.

I am very new to Joomla, so I've just been tinkering around with how to modify the template. I followed this tutorial http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EqVgCfxW4ms on how to correctly implement the extension. I do not get the same results as they do. Unfortunately, I get the following error messages:

```
Strict Standards: Only variables should be assigned by reference in C:\xampp\htdocs\joomla2\plugins\content\jw_simpleImageGallery\jw_simpleImageGallery.php on line 31

Strict Standards: Only variables should be assigned by reference in C:\xampp\htdocs\joomla2\plugins\content\jw_simpleImageGallery\jw_simpleImageGallery.php on line 32

Strict Standards: Non-static method SimpleImageGalleryHelper::getTemplatePath() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\joomla2\plugins\content\jw_simpleImageGallery\jw_simpleImageGallery.php on line 109

Strict Standards: Only variables should be assigned by reference in C:\xampp\htdocs\joomla2\plugins\content\jw_simpleImageGallery\jw_simpleImageGallery\includes\helper.php on line 255

Strict Standards: Non-static method SimpleImageGalleryHelper::getTemplatePath() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\joomla2\plugins\content\jw_simpleImageGallery\jw_simpleImageGallery.php on line 112

Strict Standards: Only variables should be assigned by reference in C:\xampp\htdocs\joomla2\plugins\content\jw_simpleImageGallery\jw_simpleImageGallery\includes\helper.php on line 255

Strict Standards: Non-static method SimpleImageGalleryHelper::getTemplatePath() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\joomla2\plugins\content\jw_simpleImageGallery\jw_simpleImageGallery.php on line 115

Strict Standards: Only variables should be assigned by reference in C:\xampp\htdocs\joomla2\plugins\content\jw_simpleImageGallery\jw_simpleImageGallery\includes\helper.php on line 255

Strict Standards: Non-static method SimpleImageGalleryHelper::renderGallery() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\joomla2\plugins\content\jw_simpleImageGallery\jw_simpleImageGallery.php on line 149

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 10485760 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 11264 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\joomla2\plugins\content\jw_simpleImageGallery\jw_simpleImageGallery\includes\helper.php on line 105
```

This is the only text on the page--not even the other portions of the template show up. Following advice given to someone on the problem, I turned off the error reporting, but not surprisingly that just gave me a plain, white page instead of telling me what was wrong.

The person who asked the following seemed to have the same problem as me http://forum.joomlaworks.net/simple-image-gallery-(plugin)/(gallery)gallery-name(gallery)-question/ but I checked the permissions on my cache folder, and it appears to be write-able.

I'm out of ideas on how to solve this problem. Has anyone had the same problem or have ideas on where the problem could be? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had a `Strict Standards:` once on my site. Lucky for me, it was on WAMP at th time, so I had access to php.ini and was able to add a small code snippet to prevent the error from appearing again.

so, if you do have access to your php.ini then open it and search for

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

and replace with:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
```

Comment: I'm using XAMPP at this point, so I have access to the php.ini file. I've changed the error_reporting from error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE to error_reporting=E_ALL | E_STRICT , but it doesn't seem to make a difference. :( Any other ideas?

Comment: are you sure you have changed the correct line? cause adding that line of code should turn off Strict Standards errors

Comment: I think it should be changed to `error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_STRICT);`